# unable to access property of one class in another

Tags: c#, properties, reference

I have following two classes

```
 public class Properties1
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual Properties2 Pro { get; set; }
 }

public class Properties2
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FName{ get; set; }
 }
```

I am trying to get data from dataset and convert it into list of Properties1 and also trying to access FName property of class Properties2 inside class Properties1 as shown below

```
List<Properties1> Properties1List = new List<Properties1>();

Properties1List = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Properties1
                        {
                            ID = dataRow.Field<int>("id"),
                            Name= dataRow.Field<string>("Name"),
                            Pro.FName= dataRow.Field<string>("FName")
                        }).ToList();
```

The problem is that i am not able to access Pro.FName property inside above code

`Pro.FName= dataRow.Field<string>("FName")` is showing error

Comment: no need you can ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign the value this way.
You need to create an instance of `Properties2` using object initializer:

```
Properties1List = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Properties1
    {
        ID = dataRow.Field<int>("id"),
        Name = dataRow.Field<string>("Name"),
        Pro = new Properties2 { 
            FName = dataRow.Field<string>("FName")
        }
    }).ToList();
```

Note that `ID` of `Properties2` will be default (0) since you don't specify it.